# Backbone.js Form Values Remembered in History

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, web-applications, backbone.js

I'm new to the whole Backbone (and I'm actually not much of a JavaScript programmer yet), and I'm running into issues with a filter form.

Basically I have a database that my backbone collection gets populated from. On the page, there is a filter section where I can checkmark things such as: "Jobstatus: Running, Completed, Failed, etc..." Or input such as "User name: test0." All that works great until I started paginating my results.

I have a router set up to handle #page/:page. This works as well, say I go to page 2 with no filters checked, and then on page 2 I check some filters (which right now sets my results back to page 1 by using navigate(page/1)), when I hit my back button, I go back to page 2 (since that is where my no filter results were last on), but my filter box is still checked.

So if there are 10 rows per page and I have 14 results with no filters. I go to page 2 to see results 11-14, check a filter that returns me to page 1 with a total of 5 results, and then i hit back. I am now on page 2 of those filtered results seeing rows 11-5 of 5...

Is there anyway for the history to remember the form checkboxes and other inputs? So if I hit back in the situation I describe, it goes to page 2, but with the form filters removes as they were prior.

I was thinking I'd have to use routes for every value on the form... but hoping there is a better way of doing this (hopefully without rewriting the entire code as well).

Any help is appreciated.

I have two main views for input: one tied to the filter form, one for the pagination selection. The filter form view calls another view for the results (which is ties to a collection of rows).

Here is the filter form view:

```
 var FilterForm = Backbone.View.extend({
            events: {
                "submit": "refreshData",
                "change input": "refreshData"
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this.refreshData();
            },

            refreshData: function () {
                Backbone.history.navigate('page/1');
                pageNumberModel.set('pageNumber', 1);

                this.newPage();
            },
            newPage: function () {
                var pageNumber = pageNumberModel.get('pageNumber');
                var rowsPerPage = pageNumberModel.get('rowsPerPage');
                var startRow = ((pageNumber * rowsPerPage) - rowsPerPage) + 1;
                var endRow = startRow + (rowsPerPage - 1);

                $('#startrow').val(startRow);
                $('#endrow').val(endRow);

                var inputData = this.$el.serializeArray();
                var inputDatareduced = _(inputData).reduce(function (acc, field) {
                    acc[field.name] = field.value;
                    return acc;
                });

                $.get("Database.aspx", inputData, function (outputData) {
                    jobQueueRows.set($.parseJSON($.parseJSON(outputData)['JobQueue']));
                    jobQueueRowsView.render();

                    pageNumberModel.set($.parseJSON($.parseJSON(outputData)['Pagination']));
                    pageNumberView.render();
                    rowNumberView.render();
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a filterModel for your FilterForm view and using that to hold the state. Here is a reference implementation.

**FilterModel:**

```
var FilterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    if( !this.get('filters')) 
      this.set({filters: new Array()});
  },
  applyFilter: function(key){
    var filters = this.get("filters");
    set("filters", _.union(filters, key));
    return this;
  },
  removeFilter: function(key){
    var filters = this.get("filters");
    set("filters", _.without(filters, key));
    return this;
  },
  defaults: {
    fooFilters: [ 
    {key: "size", label: "Filter By Size"},
    {key: "color", label: "Past Week"}]
  }
});
```

**Bind a handler in your view to update the filter model:**

```
 filterClicked: function (e) {
   var filter = $(e.target);
   if(filter.is(':checked'))
     this.model.applyFilter(filter.attr("id"));
   else
     this.model.removeFilter(filter.attr("id"));
 },
```

**Modify your filter template to apply the models state to your checkboxes when rendering:**

```
<ul id="fooFilters" class="foo-filter-list">
  <% _.each(fooFilters, function(f) { %>
  <li>
     <label for="<%=f.key%>"><%=f.name%></label> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="<%=f.key%>" <%if($.inArray(f.key, filters) === -1 {%>checked<%}%>/>
  </li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```